# Text disappeared after select next input - React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native

I create Sign In page in React Native for Android Phones. And now I get a little problem with displaying text. When the user opens Sign In screen and type his Email or Username and then clicks on the password field all from previously field will be "removed" or 'hidden'. This is code for the screen Sign In:

```
import React from 'react'
import { 
View, 
TextInput, 
StyleSheet, 
TouchableOpacity, 
Dimensions,
// AsyncStorage 
} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { SafeAreaConsumer } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

import axios from 'axios';

import {getAppLangCode} from '../helpers/store';

import {mediumFontFamily} from '../constants/Colors';
import {translate} from "../helpers/i18n";
import {getUserDatas} from '../helpers/user';


import BackButton from '../components/inners/BackButton';
import TextRegular from '../components/ui/TextRegular';
import TextMedium from '../components/ui/TextMedium';
import TextHeavy from '../components/ui/TextHeavy';

import Loader from '../components/Loader';
import ErrorSuccessPopup from '../components/ErrorSuccessPopup';

// const wHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

export default class SignInScreen extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = {
    headerShown: false,
    headerTransparent: true,
    title: 'Please sign in',
};

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        log: '',
        password: '',
        validating: false,
        focus: '',

        isSuccess: false, 
        title: translate('login_wrong'),
        message: '',
        isError: false,
    }
    this._ismounted = true;
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    this._ismounted = false;
}
// static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
//     return {

//         title: translate('chat_screen'),
//         headerLeft: () => {
//             return <BackButton isBlack={true} onPress={navigation.goBack} style={{marginLeft: 10}}/>
//         },
//     };
// };
toForgetPwd = ()=>{
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ForgetPwd');
}
toRegister = () => {
   this.props.navigation.navigate('Register');
}
onInputChange = (name)=>(text)=>{
    this.setState({[name]:text})
}
onFucusInput = (name) =>{
    this.setState({focus: name})
}
_signInAsync = async () => {
    const _self = this
    const {log,password} = _self.state
    if(log.length < 3 || password.length < 3){
        _self.setState({ isError: true, message:translate('login_enter_email'), title:translate('login_wrong') })
        return;
    }

    _self.setState({ validating: true });

    const lang = await getAppLangCode();

    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `/login`, 
        data: {
            log,
            password,
            lang: lang,
        },
    }).then(res => {
        //Set the results to the people array.
        // console.log(res.data);
        const {success} = res.data
        const title = null != res.data.title ? res.data.title : '';
        const message = null != res.data.message ? res.data.message : '';
        if( success ){
            _self.saveToStorage(res.data.data).then(rt=>{
                if( _self._ismounted ){
                    if( rt == true ){
                        _self.setState({ isSuccess: true, validating: false, message, title })
                    }else{
                        _self.setState({ isSuccess: true, validating: false, message:'Failed to store auth', title:translate('login_wrong') })
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{
            _self.setState({ isError: true, validating: false, message, title })
        }
        //Error handle the promise and set your errorMessage
    }).catch(err => {
        _self.setState({ validating: false, isError: true });
        console.log(err)
    } );

}

saveToStorage = async (userData) => {
    
    let rt = false;
    //if (userData) {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({
                isLoggedIn: true,
                authToken: userData.auth_token,
                id: userData.user_id,
                name: userData.user_login
            }));
            // await getUserDatas() // .then(rt=>console.log(rt))
            getUserDatas() // .then(rt=>console.log(rt))
            
            rt = true
        } catch (error) {
            // Error saving data
            rt = false;
            // if( null != error.message )
        }
        // return true;
    //}
    
    return rt;
}

nextField = ()=>{
    this.password.focus()
}
errorButton(){
    const {apColors} = this.props;
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.setState({ isError: false });}}>
            <View style={[styles.popupButton,{backgroundColor: apColors.appColor,}]}>
                <TextHeavy style={styles.loginButtonText}>{translate('login_try_again')}</TextHeavy>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
successButton(){
    const {apColors} = this.props;
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onPressDone() }>
            <View style={[styles.popupButton,{backgroundColor: apColors.appColor,}]}>
                <TextHeavy style={styles.loginButtonText}>{translate('login_done')}</TextHeavy>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
_onPressDone(){
    this.setState({ isSuccess: false });
    const {route,navigation} = this.props;
    const loggedInRoute = route.params?.loggedInRoute ?? 'Home';
    const backRoute = route.params?.backRoute ?? 'Home';
    switch (loggedInRoute){
        case 'Profile':
            navigation.navigate( 'ProfileStack', { screen: 'Profile', params: {backRoute} } )
            break;
        case 'Bookings':
            navigation.navigate( 'BookingsStack', { screen: 'Bookings', params: {backRoute} } )
            break;
        case 'Bookmarks':
            navigation.navigate( 'BookmarksStack', { screen: 'Bookmarks', params: {backRoute} } )
            break;
        default: 
            navigation.navigate( loggedInRoute, {backRoute} )
    }
    
}
_renderGreeting(){
    const {apColors} = this.props;
    return (
        <>
            <TextHeavy style={[styles.loginGreeting,{color: apColors.hText,}]}>{translate('login_hi')}</TextHeavy>
            <TextHeavy style={[styles.loginGreeting,{color: apColors.hText,}]}>{translate('login_welcome')}</TextHeavy>
        </>
    )
}
_onGoBack(){
    
    // const backRoute = this.props.navigation.getParam('backRoute', 'Home');
    const backRoute = this.props.route.params?.backRoute ?? 'Home';
    this.props.navigation.navigate(backRoute)
}
_renderHeader(cstyle = {}){
    // {top: 30 + insets.top}
    const {apColors} = this.props;
    return (
        <View style={[styles.navBar,cstyle]}>
            <BackButton color={apColors.backBtn} onPress={ () => this._onGoBack() }/>
        </View>
    )
}
_renderFooter(){
    const {apColors} = this.props;
    return (
        <View style={styles.signUp}>
            <TextRegular style={[styles.signUpText,{color: apColors.pText,}]}>{translate('dont_have_account')}</TextRegular>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toRegister}>
                <TextMedium style={[styles.signUpButton,{color: apColors.pText,}]}>{translate('sign_up')}</TextMedium>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
    )
}

render() {
    const {apColors} = this.props;
    const {focus,validating,isSuccess,isError,title,message} = this.state
    let logStyle = [styles.textInput,{borderColor: apColors.separator,color: apColors.pText}],
        pwdStyle = [styles.textInput,{borderColor: apColors.separator,color: apColors.pText}];
    if( focus == 'log' ) logStyle = [logStyle,{borderColor: apColors.inputFocus,}]
    if( focus == 'password' ) pwdStyle = [pwdStyle,{borderColor: apColors.inputFocus,}]
    
    // return null;
    return (
        <SafeAreaConsumer style={{flex: 1}}>
            {insets => <View style={[styles.container,{backgroundColor: apColors.appBg,paddingTop: insets.top,paddingBottom: insets.bottom,paddingLeft: insets.left,paddingRight: insets.right}]}>
                {this._renderHeader()}

                <Loader loading={validating}/>
                
                <ErrorSuccessPopup isSuccess={isSuccess} isError={isError} title={title} message={message} successButton={this.successButton()} errorButton={this.errorButton()}/>

                <View style={styles.loginInner}>
                    {this._renderGreeting()}

                    <TextRegular style={[styles.fieldLabel,{color: apColors.fieldLbl,marginTop:40}]}>{translate('user_email')}</TextRegular>
                    <TextInput 
                        // placeholder="Username or Email"
                        style={logStyle}
                        onChangeText={this.onInputChange('log')}
                        onFocus={e=>this.onFucusInput('log')}
                        returnKeyType='next'
                        onSubmitEditing = {this.nextField}
                        autoCorrect={false}
                        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        autoCompleteType="off"
                        keyboardType="email-address"
                    />
                    <TextRegular style={[styles.fieldLabel,{color: apColors.fieldLbl,}]}>{translate('password')}</TextRegular>
                    <TextInput 
                        // placeholder="Password"
                        style={pwdStyle}
                        onChangeText={this.onInputChange('password')}
                        onFocus={e=>this.onFucusInput('password')}
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                        returnKeyType='done'
                        ref={input=>this.password = input}
                        autoCorrect={false}
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                        // autoCompleteType="off"
                        // keyboardType="visible-password"

                    />

                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toForgetPwd}>
                        <TextRegular style={[styles.forgetPassword,{color: apColors.appColor,}]}>{translate('forget_password')}</TextRegular>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <View style={styles.spacer}/>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._signInAsync}>
                        <View style={[styles.loginButton,{backgroundColor: apColors.appColor,}]}>
                            <TextHeavy style={styles.loginButtonText}>{translate('login')}</TextHeavy>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    
                    

                </View>
                
                {this._renderFooter()}

            </View>}
        </SafeAreaConsumer>
    );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    
    flex:1,
    // alignItems:'center',
    // justifyContent:'center'

    minHeight: Dimensions.get('window').height - 200,
},
navBar: {
    // position: 'absolute',
    // top: 52,
    // // marginTop: 52,
    // left: 0,
    // right: 0,
    // zIndex: 200,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 15,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    // backgroundColor: 'red',
    paddingTop: 8,
    paddingBottom: 7,
    
},
loginInner: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 50,
    paddingHorizontal: 30,

    // backgroundColor: 'red',
},
loginGreeting: {
    
    fontSize: 34,
},
fieldLabel:{
    fontSize: 17,
    
    marginTop: 20,
},

textInput:{
    // margin:0,
    // marginTop:20,
    // height:40,
    // backgroundColor:'red',
    // // borderRadius:20,
    // paddingLeft:15,
    // // fontSize: AppFontSize,
    // // fontFamily: AppFontFamily,
    // borderRadius: 4,
    // width: 150,
    // flex: 1,
    height: 35,
    // marginTop: 5,
    paddingVertical: 5,

    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    fontSize: 17,
    fontFamily: mediumFontFamily,
},
forgetPassword: {
    marginTop: 35,
    fontSize: 17,
    
    textAlign: 'right',
},
spacer: {
    height: 60,
},
loginButton: {
    
    height: 44,
    borderRadius: 8,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    // marginTop: 60,
},
loginButtonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 15,
    textAlign: 'center',

},
signUp: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    // alignSelf: 'flex-end'
    // position: 'absolute',
    // bottom: 30,
    // left: 0,
    // right: 0,
    marginBottom: 15,
},
signUpText: {
    
    fontSize: 15,
    lineHeight: 20,
},
signUpButton: {
    
    fontSize: 15,
    lineHeight: 17,
    marginLeft: 5,
},
popupButton: {
    
    height: 35,
    borderRadius: 8,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 30,
    marginTop: 20
},
})
```

Where I have a mistake? How to solve this problem? Thanks all for help.

Comment: Can you share the whole script? Like what are doing in these two methods `onChangeText={this.onInputChange('log')}
        onFocus={e=>this.onFucusInput('log')}`

Comment: I update question you can look now complete code on page Sign In @praveen-me

Comment: If you try and input in text field Username or Email and try to enter your password, username or Email will disappear... I don't know where is mistake... @praveen-me